# What Android 5.x/6.x check is disabling TCP when connecting to an ad-hoc network?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I recently noticed in CyanogenMod 12.1 (Android 5.1.1) that Google implemented a network availability check that goes beyond determining if a network interface is available. I think it might have something to do with this: ["In Android 5.1, Your Device Will No Longer Connect to WiFi Networks with No Internet Access"](http://www.androidheadlines.com/2015/03/android-5-1-device-will-no-longer-connect-wifi-networks-no-internet-access.html)

The following details aren't important but I think I need to lay down the networking setup. I've been working with a root'ed Android device that enables ad-hoc networking at the command line. Similar to the following:

```
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid AdhocNetwork
iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
iwconfig wlan0 power 12
iwconfig wlan0 commit

ifconfig wlan0 ip 192.168.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig wlan0 up

/system/bin/wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant_wlan0.conf
```

The wpa_supplicant_wlan0.conf consists of the basic following:

```
update_config=0
ctrl_interface=/data/misc/wifi/sockets/wlan0
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=2
fast_reauth=0
network={
ssid="AdhocNetwork"
scan_ssid=1
mode=1
key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

It's pretty standard and the resulting configuration works generally.

```
/system/xbin/ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F8:A9:D0:63:2A:3A
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3947 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:232083 (226.6 KiB)  TX bytes:196916 (192.3 KiB)
./iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"AdhocNetwork"  Nickname:""
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Cell: 72:7D:6C:11:9F:75
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm
          Retry min limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Managementmode:All packets received
          Link Quality=5/5  Signal level=-35 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

The Android Connection Manager "Wifi" is set to "off" and I manually setup the network.

Now, with Android 5.1.1 the same setup also works ok, until I realized that from an Android app I could only UDP broadcast/unicast, and TCP would always return/throw something like:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.10.200 (port 8888): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Specifically, on Android 5.1.1, this will work fine:

```
DatagramSocket multicastClient = new DatagramSocket();
multicastClient.setBroadcast(true);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
multicastClient.send(packet);
```

The broadcast is sent from my app using the Android API. However with this TCP socket code:

```
import java.net.Socket;
...
Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
```

An exception is thrown immediately. No timeout, nothing.

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.10.200 (port 8888): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

From the shell I can ping and natcat TCP to the IP address. I have no problems accessing anything over the ad-hoc network:

```
ping 192.168.10.200
nc 192.168.10.200 8888
```

To me it looks like there's some TCP only block in the Android API included with 5.x/6.x that prevents connections from even being tried.

It's very frustrating and I can't find a solution. Maybe someone has a clue. I've already tried:

```
settings put global tether_dun_required 0
```

;and pulling the settings.db and rooting around in there for clues. I think it's an actual function check in Android itself that might not be bypassed easy.

I'm currently building our CyanogenMod ROM from source, so I'm not afraid to tweak it, but I need a clue. Anything will help. Thanks!

Comment: Since Ad-hoc networks are not offically supported by android, I am not really surprised that an update can break them.

Comment: Half the tweaks that CyanogenMod, NetHunter, or any Android ROM applies are common to Linux. I've rebuilt numerous Android Linux kernels with common Linux support that AOSP clumsily and randomly breaks. You do realize that there was a time when Adhoc was supported in Android right? What about their implementation of SELinux and PIE that broke some of Google's own apps in the store? The point is what is and isn't supported is as grey as whatever Google chooses to break on any given release. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I hate the way Google treats developers. And the way they handled this particular request for AdHoc wifi is nothing short from spit in the face - have the issue dragging for 7 years and than close as 'outdated'. My comment is a general thing, in line 'has to say something, don't really have anything meaningful to say'.

Comment: No joke. You're of course right about that infamous adhoc issue track. I think I posted to it twice myself. In this case I really want to see if it's time to truly give up or if we can get another release or two of relatively easy ad-hoc support. Android has had so much potential for mesh networks and it routinely kills it for stupid carrier reasons.